# How to remove duplicate values from SQL inner join tables?

Tags: oracle, duplicates, inner-join

I have two tables:

**Table 1:**

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| ID        | Value     | other            |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| 123456    | 5         | 12               |
| 987654    | 7         | 15               |
| 456789    | 6         | 22               |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| ID        | Type      | other            |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| 123456    | 00        | 2                |
| 123456    | 01        | 6                |
| 123456    | 02        | 4                |
| 987654    | 00        | 7                |
| 987654    | 01        | 8                |
| 456789    | 00        | 6                |
| 456789    | 01        | 16               |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

Now I perform the inner join:

```
SELECT
  table1.ID, table2.TYPE, table1.value, table2.other 
FROM
  table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Here the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d56d9/2)

**Result Table:**

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| ID        | Type      | Value   | other            |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| 123456    | 00        | 5       | 2                |
| 123456    | 01        | 5       | 6                |
| 123456    | 02        | 5       | 4                |
| 987654    | 00        | 7       | 7                |
| 987654    | 01        | 7       | 8                |
| 456789    | 00        | 6       | 6                |
| 456789    | 01        | 6       | 16               |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
```

This is totally what I expected but not what I need.
Because if I now want to get the Value per ID the Value gets doubled or tripled for the first cause.

**Desired Table:**

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| ID        | Type      | Value   | other            |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| 123456    | 00        | 5       | 2                |
| 123456    | 01        | -       | 6                |
| 123456    | 02        | -       | 4                |
| 987654    | 00        | 7       | 7                |
| 987654    | 01        | -       | 8                |
| 456789    | 00        | 6       | 6                |
| 456789    | 01        | -       | 16               |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+
```

I tried to achieve a similar output by counting the rows per id and dividing the sum of Value by that count but it did not seem to work and is not the desired output.

Also, I tried grouping but this did not seem to achieve the desired output.

One thing to mention is that the DB I am working with is an ORACLE SQL DB.

Comment: Is it  always true that if Type '00' contains a value, the same will be present for Type 01 and Type 02  and so on for  each id?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes, see the SQLfiddle link I put there the value gets copied for the other Types aswell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select table1.id
     , table2.type
     , case
           when row_number() over (partition by table1.id order by table2.type) = 1
           then table1.value
       end as "VALUE"
     , table2.other
from   table1
       join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
order by 1, 2;
```

(This is Oracle SQL syntax. Your SQL Fiddle (thanks!) was set to MySQL, which as far as I know doesn't have analytic functions like `row_number()`.)

Comment: Works perfectly, im going to note that I use the correct setting in Fiddle the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` block to display `NULL` for which it is NOT equal to `MIN` value of `type`

```
SELECT table1.ID,
       table2.TYPE,
       CASE
          WHEN table2.TYPE =
                  MIN (table2.TYPE)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY table1.id ORDER BY table2.TYPE)
          THEN
             Table1.VALUE
       END
          VALUE,
       table2.other
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

Comment: This is where my question becomes inaccurate, im sorry for that. Do you know about an option, if the TYPE is not always '00' but sometimes the lowest is like '123'

Comment: @M.Wagner : Modified now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the result.

```
  select   t1.ID,
           t2.type, 
           t1.value,
           t2.other
    from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    inner join (select ID, min(type) mv
    from table2
    group by id) m
    on t2.id = m.id
    and t2.type = m.mv
    union all
    select t1.ID,
           t2type, 
           null,
           t2.other
    from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    and not exists (
    select 1 from (
    select ID, min(type) mv
    from table2
    group by id) m
    where t2.id = m.id
    and t2.type = m.mv
    )

    order by id,type
```